# Firefox 3.5: Address Bar: Remove the Favicon box (blue box) completely?

Tags: firefox, ssl, security

Is their anyway to get rid of the favicon box completely in the address bar (not just the favicon) and also those annoying blue boxes that appear when you connect to some secured websites (see below for examples)?

[image: google favicon]

[image: google ssl]

Comment: I suspect a userchrome.css solution could be worked out, but first you'd have to find the name of the blue box so you could make it disappear or however you'd do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the following rule in the [userChrome.css](http://www.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html#usercss) file in the chrome folder in [your profile folder](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles).

```
#identity-box { display: none !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Half of your request is here : [Quick Tip: Disable Favicons in Firefox](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/internet/firefox/quick-tip-disable-favicons-in-firefox/).

For the other half you might install the add-on [Old Location Bar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7637), which makes Firefox 3's location bar look and act more like Firefox 2's old location bar.